# ember-cordova cannot multi-upload photos with x-file-input

Tags: ember.js

I am using the plugin from https://github.com/thefrontside/emberx-file-input. I want to multi-select photos while uploading. I can do it from the laptop. But when I use ember-cordova and create app on my android device, I cannot multi-select photos even though I have added the multiple = true in the code. Here is the code below,

```
{{#x-file-input multiple=true action=(action "selectImg")}}
```

Comment: Do you find my solution was helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a block or inline component invocation? You use `#` at the start of component name, it means you have to close it by `{{/x-file-input}}`, I just try to understand if it just a typo..

Answer (score 0):

I see `emberx-file-input` addon is out of date since the last activity in Github is Dec 2017. I suggest you to use [ember-file-upload](https://github.com/adopted-ember-addons/ember-file-upload) addon.

If you are implementing the file upload module only buy now i would suggest you to go with `ember-file-upload` addon.